# Relation between sum and integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration

The [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin,and%20the%20machinery%20of%20calculus) helps to relate sums and integrals. I am particularly interested in one case of equation and want to get it clarified.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{x}f(n)-\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du\right)$$
What will this lead to according to Euler maclaurin formula?
(I have assumed that $f(x)$ is a continuous function and defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)-\int_0^\infty f(u)du=\tfrac{1}{2}f(0)-\tfrac{1}{12}f'(0)+\tfrac{1}{720}f'''(0)-\tfrac{1}{30240}f'''''(0)+\cdots$